# Network Tracing Google Ad Manager Mobile Ads SDK iOS

Tags: ios

I have successfully installed Google Ad Manager Mobile Ads SDK in my iOS application, now i want to know the request rate of those ads. I want to know the network calling of those ads. I tried to view using Charles Proxy by passing the identifier for ads, but unfortunately Charles Proxy doesn't show any log. 
Further, https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/network-tracing using this link, I got the "enablement url" for my bundle identifier from google, and as described in this link, i added the "enablement url" in my notes app of iPhone device and re-launched the app. But i am not able to get any logs for the Network Tracing for the ads.

Kindly help what i am missing in this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should configure your iPhone device to match with Charles. I applied following document and I saw the logs on Charles.

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/ios/getting-started-1/

I hope it helps you, too.